# AngularJS routing causing issues with server calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, node-webkit

I am using `AngularJS` in a nodewebkit application.
I have three views:

1. Home.html
2. Conversation.html
3. Login.html

On login, I am calling

```
$state.go('home.main');
```

which calls

```
$stateProvider.state('home.main', {
            url: '/home',  
            views: {
                "mainContent": {
                    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                    controller: 'loginController'
                }
            }
}
```

In main html, I am making a server call (through socket.io) to get all conversations.
Since data is huge, it takes some time to load it and in this time gap i.e. before user gets response from server, If user clicks on Logout, It takes user back to login page.

```
 $scope.logout = function(){  
    //Logout Logic  
      $state.go('login');
 }
```

i.e. it calls

```
 $stateProvider.state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: "loginController"
        });
```

Now When a user is trying to login, server responds to call made for getting conversations allowing user to take him to /home/conv.html.

I don't want to disable `Logout` button while data is being sent from server to client.
Is there any way on routing from /home to /login, we can cancel all server calls?

Comment: You can disconnect socket using `socket.disconnect()` see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code from https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki:

```
$stateProvider.state("contacts", {
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
  resolve: { title: 'My Contacts' },
  controller: function($scope, title){
    $scope.title = 'My Contacts';
  },
  onEnter: function(title){
    if(title){ ... do something ... }
  },
  onExit: function(title){
    if(title){ ... do something ... }
  }
})
```

The onExit event will be triggered when you move from home.main to another route. So you should register to handle the event at where you declare the home.main route. In this event, you can cancel all server calls. As you are using socket.io, I suggest you use the function `socket.removeAllListeners();`